# How do I make the edit and cancel link appear only if its the logged in user is the one who created the object? Django

Tags: python, django

The edit and delete function works fine but I cant make it specific that it only appears to the person that created that object?

```
{% for job in jobs %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ job.job }}</td>
    <td>{{ job.location }}</td>
    <td><a href="/jobs/{{ job.id }}/view">View</a> <a href="/main">Add</a> <a href="/jobs/{{ job.id }}/edit">Edit</a> <a href="/jobs/{{ job.id }}/delete">Cancel</a> </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your models.py too

Answer (score 0):

Inside `for` loop you can check if it's the same user who created it and if `succeed` display button otherwise no need to append buttons as

```
{% for job in jobs %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ job.job }}</td>
    <td>{{ job.location }}</td>
    <td><a href="/jobs/{{ job.id }}/view">View</a> 
        <a href="/main">Add</a>
        {% if job.creator == request.user %}
            <a href="/jobs/{{ job.id }}/edit">Edit</a>
            <a href="/jobs/{{ job.id }}/delete">Cancel</a>
         {% endif %}
     </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**NOTE :** I have used `creator`as `ForeignKey` reference to your`Job` model.